# reverse proxy with multiple sessions in same browser

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

My reverse proxy seems to be mostly working, though when I open sessions to different backend servers, within the same browser, I get this message from the browser (tested with Chrome and IE):

```
Already a session is running in this browser, so opening the same session
```

Once I open the 2nd session, the two sessions interfere in such a way that one of them is logged out.

The two request URLs are:

```
https://proxy-server/backend1/index.html
https://proxy-server/backend2/index.html
```

The reverse proxy maps these requests to:

```
https://backend1:1234/index.html  and
https://backend2:1234/index.html
```

I guess this is related to the cookies?  So I compared them, and each has unique cookie contents, e.g.:

```
Session to backend1:
  QSESSIONID: c1f9468714084ee2fePE6l5x3FqyPl

Session to backend2:
  QSESSIONID: 06b2468a5a0509eb1aWoJRH8TpslxC
```

What do I need to configure in the Reverse-Proxy to keep these sessions from interfering with each other?

Thanks,
Matt.

Comment: share your config first

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question... To cut straight to the answer, I needed to add `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` to my `<VirtualHost>`:

```
<Location "/backend1">
  ...
  ProxyPass https://backend1:1234/
  ProxyPassReverse https://backend1:1234/
  ...
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /backend1
  ...
</Location>
```

To discover what I needed to add, it required tracing the `Set-Cookie` header on the backend server as well as on the proxy server.

On the backend I'm using lighttpd.  To trace the backend request/reply:

```
server.modules += ("mod_accesslog")
accesslog.use-syslog = "enable"
accesslog.syslog-level = 6
accesslog.format = "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" \"C:%{Cookie}i\" \"S-C:%{Set-Cookie}o\" %>s %b"
```

The Reverse-Proxy is running Apache, so I added this to my `<VirtualHost>`...

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" \"C:%{Cookie}i\" \"S-C:%{Set-Cookie}o\" %>s %b"
TransferLog "/store/log/httpd_access_log"
```

Now armed with logging details, I could see what was happening...

After the initial login-screen, a session is established and the backend server creates the Cookie content and adds it to the `Set-Cookie` header.  The clue I needed was that it specifies `Set-Cookie` with `Path=/`.  To stop sessions from different backend servers interfering with each other, I needed to make the `Path` attribute dependent on the backend server name.  That's what the `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` does for me.

The Proxy sees the `Set-Cookie` header and maps the `Path` attribute.

The logs showed, on lighttpd (edited for viewing pleasure):

```
"POST /api/session HTTP/1.1" "C:i18next=en-us" "S-C:SID=3bmx; path=/; secure"
```

And after this response passes through the Proxy, it is modified by the       `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` directive to be:

```
POST /backend1/api/session HTTP/1.1 C:i18next=en-us S-C:SID=3bmx; path=/backend1;secure
```

Now the Cookie path is dependent on the name of the backend server.

Matt.